# mysql query resulting in numerous output makes php page go blank

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, sql-like

I use like query forsearch function. All goes well when I search for keywords that are few in db. However when the keyword is "popular" in db, the screen goes blank page.

```
function dbSearch($q) //$q is array of keywords
{

  global $mainframe, $option;

  $db =& JFactory::getDBO();

  $str = implode("%' AND text LIKE '%", $q);
  $str = str_replace("AND text LIKE '%-", "AND text NOT LIKE '%", $str);

  $lim   = $mainframe->getUserStateFromRequest("$option.limit", 'limit', 100, 'int'); 
  $lim0  = JRequest::getVar('limitstart', 0, '', 'int');
  $query = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM `table` WHERE type=4 AND text LIKE '%".$str."%' ORDER BY ref ASC";

  $db->setQuery( $query );
  $rows = $db->loadObjectList();
  $count = count($rows);

  if ($db->getErrorNum())
  {
    echo $db->stderr();
    return false;
  }

  $db->setQuery('SELECT FOUND_ROWS();'); 
  jimport('joomla.html.pagination');
  $pageNav = new JPagination( $db->loadResult(), $lim0, $lim );

  HTML_output::showFoundResults($rows, $pageNav, $count);
}
```

Is something wrong in the query above? why it fails on numerous results?

Comment: May be a maximum_execution_time error, take a look at error log. And try to build/use a keyword index instead of using `LIKE`.

Comment: Turn error_reporting on both in your system and in Joomla configuration to see what's goin' wrong

Comment: Is it a situation where the more keywords you're searching for when it becomes an issue?  Or are you able to see that there should be a large number of results?

Comment: @RobertPitt enabled reporting, logging... nothing changes

Comment: @dmcnelis I just know that the string is contained in almost all row in db... however in blanks out by query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that your PHP is taking to long to generate the results based on the query. Your apache error log is likely going to show a PHP timout error as the page too longer than 30 seconds to generate the page.

Try setting the LIMIT to something much smaller like 10 and see if it is able to generate a page.

Another thing you can do is skip 'stopwords' as they are called, words like 'and', 'the', etc. that are very common in a language. Search engines do this, and a quick search will give you more details and lists of stopwords.

You can see how long the query takes to execute by running the query in a tool like phpMyAdmin.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM `table` WHERE type=4 AND text LIKE '%jabberwocky%' ORDER BY ref ASC";
```

Compared to

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM `table` WHERE type=4 AND text LIKE '%the%' ORDER BY ref ASC";
```

In the same query tool, if you put 'EXPLAIN ' in front of the query, MySQL will return a list of all the actions it had to do to complete the query.

One thing to note, is that a search for the word 'the' will also return results for 'theory' the way your query is constructed. Not an easy thing to code around without going to a REGEX query.

Comment: The LIMIT solved my issue, after spending hours pulling my hair out.

Answer (score 0):

Blank page comes after how many time ? 
What is the value of max_execution_time directive in php configuration file ?

If it's the same time try to increase this value, or make some improvement on query or table.

Comment: I tried to increase the max_execution_time directive however no effect. How you advise the query can be improved?

Answer (score 0):

Blank pages are normally indicative of a fatal error, or possibly a parse error. If you have set error logging to maximum and its still showing a blank page, then try adding
[code]
php_value display_errors 1
php_value display_startup_errors 1
[/code]

to your .htaccess file